# How do I extract the results of a multicast delegate at runtime?

Tags: c#, delegates

Not sure if this is possible but im wondering how I catch the return of two methods that are assigned to the same delegate (multicast). I basically wondered if there is a way to catch each return value? Perhaps I have to iterate over it, not really sure..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace MutiCastDelegate2
{
    class Program
    {

        delegate string HelloWorldDelegate();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HelloWorldDelegate myDel1 = ReturnHelloWorld;
            HelloWorldDelegate myDel2 = ReturnHelloWorld2;
            HelloWorldDelegate myMultiDelegate = myDel1 + myDel2;

            Console.WriteLine(myMultiDelegate());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        public static string ReturnHelloWorld()
        {
            return "Return Hello World";
        }

        public static string ReturnHelloWorld2()
        {
            return "Return Hello World 2";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) to get access to each delegate in the list, then you just have to call each one and retrieve the results:

```
var delegates = myMultiDelegate.GetInvocationList();
foreach (var d in delegates)
{
    string result = (string) d.DynamicInvoke();
}
```